# No members available in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, most-vexing-parse

I have a class

```
class Test{
public:
    Test(){};
    ~Test(){};
    void test() {cout<<"test"<<endl;};
};
```

and in main.cpp I have:

```
#include "Test.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
     Test t();
     t.test();
}
```

Is this right way to declare method or am I getting it wrong? VS2010 doesn't recognise this method at all. It states that

> expression must have a class type

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a function here:

```
Test t(); // function t(), returning a Test instance
```

Try this instead:

```
Test t;  // t is a Test instance
Test t2{}; // t2 is a Test instance, C++11 only
```

Answer (score 0):

```
First thing is that 
class Test{
public:
    Test(){};(Your Default Constructor when you will make the object this constructor will call)
    ~Test(){};(when you will release this object your destructor will call)
    void test() {cout<<"test"<<endl;};
};
Here you don't need to call manually.
```

Comment: how'd this thing get an upvote?